# Using find on map<pair, int>

Tags: c++, dictionary

How do you use find with a `const_iterator` if you have a map defined as

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> MyPair;
map<MyPair, int> MyMap;
```

with the `pair` defined as the key.

If it was just `map<int, int>`, I know how to use a `const_iterator` like

```
typedef map<int, int> MyMap;
MyMap::const_iterator it = 
      MyMap.find(0);

// etc..
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If you are not using C++11**, the most convenient is to also do a `typedef` for the map type:

```
typedef std::map<MyPair, int> map_type;
```

And then

```
map_type::const_iterator it = MyMap.find(make_pair(0, 0));
```

(I also changed the parameter passed to `find`, as a bare `int` is not compatible with your map).

**If you are using C++11**, you can also do simply

```
auto it = MyMap.find(make_pair(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 4):

Find takes a key type of your map, so in this case you need to create a `std::pair` that you want to use in the lookup.  Here's a short example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> m;

   m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(0, 0), "Hello"));
   m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(1, 0), "There"));

   auto res = m.find(make_pair(0,0));

   if(res != m.end())
   {
      cout << res->second << "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There compilation issue in the above code. Please find the correct one as below:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> m;
   std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string>::iterator res;

   m.insert(std::make_pair(make_pair(0, 0), "Hello"));
   m.insert(std::make_pair(make_pair(1, 0), "There"));

   res = m.find(make_pair(0,0));

   if(res != m.end())
   {
      cout << res->second << "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

think you could use

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> m = {
    {{ 0, 0 }, "Hello" },
    {{ 1, 0 }, "There" },
 };
```

instead of

```
m.insert(std::make_pair(make_pair(0, 0), "Hello"));
m.insert(std::make_pair(make_pair(1, 0), "There"));
```

Comment: What's this got to do with `find`?